# React App front end and Express server backend - Azure AD validation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express, jwt

I would like to authenticate a user that's received an JWT token issued by AD via an Express app in order for them to access API endpoints.

Currently, I have a frontend React app and I have registered the app with Azure.  I am using @azure/msal-react npm package to authenticate the user. That part is working great, users can log in and get a token just fine!

Now I want to take that token and pass it somehow to the express app for validation....

I setup test logic that follows the SOF link below (see link) and I inserted my own token for testing to see if I can see a decoded jwt token.

[How to use Jsonwebtoken NPM package to verify JWT token issued by Azure AD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074443/how-to-use-jsonwebtoken-npm-package-to-verify-jwt-token-issued-by-azure-ad)

I am getting the header back, which includes a nonce, alg, x5t, and kid value but I am not getting the actual body of the token back. the variable " decoded"  which is:

```
var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
var header = decoded.header
```

is coming back as "undefined"

What is the best way for receiving an Azure AD bearer JWT token in an express endpoint, then verifying/validating it ?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mention you get the header back but `decoded` is undefined? Could you clarify? Also, since you are trying with your own token, do you have `typ` set as `JWT` in the header? If not, looks like you need to set `json: true` in the options to the `decode` method as well.